# Best suited ARM based development kit for porting android OS

Tags: android, arm, porting, modbus

I am looking for a ARM based hardware development kit for porting Android OS on it. 
My objective is to port Android OS on ARM based hardware platform and write Modbus drivers to provide serial communication support for Android based mobile phones. I an going to write Android mobile Application that will communicate my hardware board through modbus drivers.

I did some Google search and found that Beagle board is most preferable for this project and also their is huge developers community available if in case of any help.

Is their any other ARM hardware platform best suited for my project?

Comment: you got to reach any conclusion ? please do share it

Answer (score 1):

Try [Technexion](http://www.technexion.com)

We're using it for our ([XLogic](http://www.xlogic.pl)) projects, we have developed similar CAN/ModBus solutions in the past and found their TAM-3517 modules to be optimal for our prototyping needs.

It's basically a SO-DIMM 200pin form factor Sitara (OMAP3, mostly Beagleboard compatible) platform, featuring most of the needed interfaces, with decent support and dev-kits. They have already ported Android onto the platform, so you just need to add your secret sauce and be done with it.

On a somewhat related note, please ping me if you're interested in collaborating on getting industrial protocols Android APIs somewhat standarized - this is a very interesting field and we could have an opportunity to establish a reference implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to www.linaro.org and see if their Android releases work for you. They already have Ice Cream Sandwich running on Panda and Snowball boards (although no releases just yet, I think), so you might like to try one of those.